# sockets sending encrypted data python

Tags: python, sockets, encryption, rsa

I am experimenting encrypting data and sending the data between a server and client script with sockets.

The data is [encrypted through rsa](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-encrypt-and-decrypt-strings-in-python/#:%7E:text=asymmetric-key%20encryption%3A).

The data transfers fine with socksets on the scripts below but I am running into an issue on the client side with decrypting the data.

`rsa.pkcs1.DecryptionError: Decryption failed`

Probably because these are two separate scripts and I think I am generating the two keys (public key and private key) twice, or something.

This is the server script with some made up data:

```
import pickle
import socket
import pickle
import rsa
import json


data = {
    "1630192500000":{"payload":94},
    "1630193400000":{"payload":95},
    "1630194300000":{"payload":96}
    }

jsondata = json.dumps(data)

publicKey, privateKey = rsa.newkeys(1024)
encMessage = rsa.encrypt(jsondata.encode(),publicKey)
print(encMessage)

HEADERSIZE = 10

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind((socket.gethostname(), 1243))
s.listen(5)


while True:
    # now our endpoint knows about the OTHER endpoint.
    clientsocket, address = s.accept()
    print(f"Connection from {address} has been established.")

    msg = pickle.dumps(encMessage)
    msg = bytes(f"{len(msg):<{HEADERSIZE}}", 'utf-8')+msg
    print(msg)
    clientsocket.send(msg)
```

client script that recieves the made up data:

```
import socket
import pickle
from cryptography.fernet import Fernet
import rsa

publicKey, privateKey = rsa.newkeys(512)



HEADERSIZE = 10

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect((socket.gethostname(), 1243))



while True:
    full_msg = b''
    new_msg = True
    while True:
        msg = s.recv(2048)
        if new_msg:
            print("new msg len:",msg[:HEADERSIZE])
            msglen = int(msg[:HEADERSIZE])
            new_msg = False

        print(f"full message length: {msglen}")

        full_msg += msg

        print(len(full_msg))

        if len(full_msg)-HEADERSIZE == msglen:
            print("full msg recvd")
            print(full_msg[HEADERSIZE:])
            print(pickle.loads(full_msg[HEADERSIZE:]))
            new_msg = True
            full_msg = b""

        
        decMessage = rsa.decrypt(full_msg, privateKey).decode()
        print("decrypted string: ", decMessage)
```

Any tips for how I can change the code greatly appreciated on how I can decrypted the data on the client side. Not alot of wisdom here any, thanks for any incite for how I can transfer the publicKey, privateKey to the client script. Is it as easy as saving to a file on the server side and then loading on the client? If so any links to tutorials or methods appreciated.

Comment: You are correct in your guess as to the error. private and public keys go together, sometimes called a keypair. You must encrypt with the public key and decrypt with the private key of the same keypair. You have generated a different keypair on the server and the client, and those keys are completely unrelated. You can certainly transfer the public key over the socket, though secure key management is much more complicated than that

Comment: I have one concern, is your `encMessage` and `full_msg` are same? Moreover, you have multiple pair of public and private key. This could the issue

Comment: You will need to share the keys. Here is a tutorial that might help: https://www.thepythoncode.com/article/encrypt-decrypt-files-symmetric-python You can make that more secure by sending over an encrypted socket using ssh which will then include all the complicated stuff you need.